# SED not Deleting lines

Tags: sed

Can anyone tell me why sed fails to delete the lines containing `0` in the last column. I have used the following and nothing seems to work.

```
sed "/0/d"
sed "/ 0 /d"
sed "/\t0\n/d"
sed "/0\n/d"
```

Output:

```
 93000000       95       95       3328   0
 99000000       96       96       3206   0
 99000000       96       96       3210   0
 99000000       96       96       3215   0
 99000000       96       96       3224   0
 99000000       96       96       3230   0
 99000000       96       96       3236   0
 99000000       96       96       3268   0
 99000000       96       96       3292   0
 99000000       96       96       3459   0
 591000000      85       85       2      2 CDL (control)
 321000000      40       40       109    4.2 COZI-TV
 585000000      84       84       8      8 NJTV
 585000000      84       84       8134   10 WTBY
 543000000      77       77       710    10.1 WLNY-10
 585000000      84       84       62     12 N12WC
 657000000      101      101      1014   14 OPTCH
```

Comment: What is the complete command you are using? At the very least, the first command listed should remove all the lines from your input (since they all contain a `0` somewhere).

Comment: `sed '/0$/d' filename` will remove all lines ending in a 0.

Comment: Yes, we're missing info here. When I copy/paste your "output" into a file, and then `sed '/0/d' /tmp/file`, I get no output (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

For deleting lines contain `0` in last column, try:

```
$ sed '/0$/d' file
591000000      85       85       2      2 CDL (control)
321000000      40       40       109    4.2 COZI-TV
585000000      84       84       8      8 NJTV
585000000      84       84       8134   10 WTBY
585000000      84       84       62     12 N12WC
657000000      101      101      1014   14 OPTCH
```

Your solutions fail because:

- `sed "/0/d"`: `/0/` meaning match line contains `0` in any position, so it will delete all your input lines.
- `sed "/ 0 /d"`: `/ 0 /` meaning match line contains `0` before and after a space. It will do nothing because your input does not match.
- `sed "/\t0\n/d"` and `sed "/0\n/d"` also don't match because the regex you used wrong way.

Conclusion, for match `0` in the last column, you must use `/0$/`. You should read `man sed` or any articles abour `regular expression` for more details.

**Updated**

According to @steeldriver's answer, I update my answer to preserve lines contains number that end with `0`:

```
$ sed '/ 0$/d' cat
591000000      85       85       2      2 CDL (control)
321000000      40       40       109    4.2 COZI-TV
585000000      84       84       8      8 NJTV
585000000      84       84       8134   10 WTBY
543000000      77       77       710    10.1 WLNY-10
585000000      84       84       62     12 N12WC
657000000      101      101      1014   14 OPTCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match newlines with `\n` (or anything else you've tried) in `sed`, since `sed` works per-line, thus newlines as you think of them aren't in scope of its working.  What you're looking for is the `$` special operator, matching End of Line:

```
sed -e '/0$/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* want to also delete lines such as that ending in `WLNY-10` then you need to be a bit more specific than even `/0$/`, for example

```
sed -r '/\s0$/d' file
```

or, if GNU sed is not available

```
sed '/[[:space:]]0$/d' file
```

or even

```
awk '$NF!=0' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` command,

```
$ awk '$NF==0 {next;}1' file
591000000      85       85       2      2 CDL (control)
321000000      40       40       109    4.2 COZI-TV
585000000      84       84       8      8 NJTV
585000000      84       84       8134   10 WTBY
543000000      77       77       710    10.1 WLNY-10
585000000      84       84       62     12 N12WC
657000000      101      101      1014   14 OPTCH
```